# How to derive least squares estimators from normal equations with work shown

Tags: least-squares, linear-model

My last question was closed, so I made a new one that is more relevant and has my full calculations thus far. I have a scenario where I have been given some information, such as normal equations from a linear model. From the information I'm given, I need to get least squares’ estimates of  1,  2, and 3. I think I am on the right track to getting the estimates, but I am still somewhat struggling. I've attached the given information and the work I have thus far, as well as a possible solution. I don't think my solution is correct, but I added it to see. I think I'm missing something simple, but we'll see.

[image]

[image]

This is one possible solution I got, but I don't think it's right. It was just something I was playing around to try. My thought process on this though was to use the other equations to derive a Beta2 and Beta3 values and then solve the three equations for 3 unknowns, but like I said, I don't think this is correct, but I threw it out there.

[image]

Comment: You haven't stated the original problem.  What is your $X$?  Where did the coefficients of your equations come from?  You appear to have *begun* with $X^\prime X$ and then later assume that $X=X^\prime X.$ This is extremely confusing for everyone: you need to *explain* what you're doing, beginning with *exactly* what the problem is you are trying to solve.